# keep resized images with the new size in memory?

Tags: javascript

is following only with javascript (without php) possible:

clip, crop or resize a image and keep the new image in memory with the new height and width?

normaly the resized image is shown in the browser with the new size. but if you have a look at the properties, the size is the same as the original image.

Comment: Yes. That is possible by using canvas.

Comment: thx. i will read some tutorials about that. maybe you have a link or better a piece of code for me?

Comment: i would suggest this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: ok, i will try and experiment with this